# PHP MySQL un identified character

Tags: php, mysql

We have script to receive data from a device. The information contains `device id`, `latitude`, `longitude` etc.

We are getting all other data except device id(which is at beginning of below string) in readable format.

```
$$�1233Oÿÿ™U095933.000,A,4949.4194,N,00839.0009,E,0.00,194,080816,
```

I have set UTF-8 in PHP code and MySQL db (where it stores data) and even in `php.ini` as `character set`.

Comment: If the problem is when getting the data from the device, then MySQL is not really relevant here. It's probably have to do with the encoding the device is using to transmit the data.

Comment: http://php.net/bin2hex